# output data from all_tab_columns

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

i have a table test with many filler columns whose values are actually the column names from some tables in the database. i want to frame a query which returns the owner,table_name,column_name for all the filler columns

```
DROP TABLE TEST;
create  table test (cat varchar2(10) , filler_1 varchar2(10), filler_2 varchar2(10));

INSERT INTO TEST
SELECT 
'A',    'DOB','BIRTH_DT' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'GENDER'    ,'T_GENDER' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'ACT_ID',   'ACT_NO' FROM DUAL;
COMMIT;
```

expected output :

```
CAT      OWNER       TABLE_NAME     COLUMN_NM
A       SCOTT        ABC            DOB
A       SCOTT        XXX            BIRTH_DT
B       HR           AAA            GENDER
B       HR           BBB            T_GENDER
C       SCOTT        CCC            ACT_ID
C       HR           DDD            ACT_NO
```

how do i achieve this using all_tab_columns as there are many filler columns of that sort.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script option using a dynamically created view. Will that work?

```
DECLARE
  sql_string VARCHAR2(4000);

  CURSOR columns_cur IS
    SELECT column_name
    FROM   all_tab_columns
    WHERE  table_name = 'TEST'
    AND    column_name LIKE 'FILLER\_%' ESCAPE '\';
BEGIN
  sql_string := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_v AS ';

  FOR r IN columns_cur LOOP
    sql_string := sql_string||' SELECT cat, '||r.column_name||' filler FROM test UNION ';
  END LOOP;

  sql_string := SUBSTR(sql_string, 1, LENGTH(sql_string) - 6);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_string;
END;
/

SELECT b.cat, a.owner, a.table_name, a.column_name column_nm
FROM   all_tab_columns a,
       test_v b
WHERE  a.column_name = b.filler
AND    a.column_name IN (
  SELECT filler
  FROM   test_v);
```

You could obviously extend this technique to include everything in one view.

Comment: Thanks but there are 30 filler columns so 30 select statements doesn't look good to me.

Comment: Is there a pattern for the "filler" columns? Do they all start with "filler_"?

Comment: Yes all columns starts with filler_ except cat

Comment: Is using PL/SQL is an option? You could probably accomplish your goal with a pipelined table, if so.

Comment: Yes any option is fine .

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use following query:

```
Select t.cat, c.owner, c.table_name, c.column_name
from all_tab_columns c
Join test t
On (c.column_name in (t.filler_1, filler_2))
```

Note: `all_tab_columns` views will give all the tables on which your user has rights and `user_tab_columns` views will give all the tables of your own user.

Cheers!!